# Retain original value in DataBase when NULL value is passed to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql

Hi I am a newbie in SQL and require help
I have a parameterized stored procedure which contains a Update query like...

```
UPDATE sometable 
SET 
    price1 =    @param1,
    price2 =    @param2,
    price3 =    @param3,
    price4 =    @param4,
WHERE
    ID = @param5
```

Now when I execute this SP by setting any of the parameters value as NULL it gets updated in DB, what  I want to know is if one of the parameters value is NULL then can we retain that columns original value in DB instead of updating it with NULL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQLServer the tidy way is to use [ISNULL(@param1, price1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).

This takes @param1 and checks if it is NULL.  If it is NULL it is replaced with the value from price1.  I like [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) as it's very readable, does what it says on the tin.

It's not ANSI SQL though, with a more flexible command existing there: [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).  It's just like [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx), but takes any number of parameters.  It searches through them in order for the first non-NULL value.  If none are found, NULL is returned...

```
UPDATE sometable 
SET 
        price1 =        ISNULL(@param1, price1),
        price2 =        ISNULL(@param2, price2),
        price3 =        ISNULL(@param3, price3),
        price4 =        ISNULL(@param4, price4)
WHERE
        ID = @param5
```

```
UPDATE sometable 
SET 
        price1 =        COALESCE(@param1, price1),
        price2 =        COALESCE(@param2, price2),
        price3 =        COALESCE(@param3, price3),
        price4 =        COALESCE(@param4, price4)
WHERE
        ID = @param5
```

Also see: "[COALESCE vs ISNULL](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html)"

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the @paramx with a CASE statement:

CASE @paramx
    WHEN NULL THEN pricex
    ELSE @paramx
END

Answer (score -1):

```
  UPDATE SET tgt.firstname = coalesce (src.new_FirstName, tgt.firstname)
```